# Bulk Inserting Data into PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have SpringBoot project which will pull a large amount of data from one database, do some kind of transformation on it, and then insert it into a table in a PostgreSQL database. This process will continue for a few billion records so performance is key.

I've been researching trying to find the best way to do this, such as using an ORM or a JDBCTemplate for example. One thing I keep seeing constantly regarding bulk inserts into PostgreSQL is the **COPY command**. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html

I'm confused because using COPY requires the data to be written into a file, and while I've seen people saying to use it I've yet to come across a case where someone mentions how to get the data into the file. Isn't writing to a file slow? If writing to a file is slow, then the performance gains that COPY does bring, does this make it be like there was no gain at all?

Comment: Is it billion records every time you run the process or is it just one time transformation?

Comment: In our case its over a billion records in total which we need to write at some point during this process. Pulling the data from the original database will be done in batches of a few thousand at a time, still working on determining the optimal batch size though for that so I'll just estimate somewhere between 5,000 to 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of data migration and conversion is better to handle in Stored procedures. Assuming that the source data is already loaded to postgres ( if not use postgres db utility to load the raw data to some flat table). Then write series of stored procs to transform the data and insert into the destination table.

I have done some complex data migration and i used this approach. If you have to do lot of complex data conversion, write some python script ( which is usually faster than spring boot/data setup), insert the parially converted data, then do some stored procs to do the final conversion.

It is better to keep the business logic to convert/massage data close to the datasource ( in stored procs) instead of pulling data to app server and reinserting them.

Hope it helps.